# Reactjs get event keycode on keyup

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get keyCode on keyUp event, but always return 0, why? I don't want to use keypress or etc. also I should use arrow function:

```
 handleKeyPress = (e, type) => {
    let KeyCode = e.charCode;
    console.log(KeyCode)
    console.log(type)
  }

 <input type="text" onKeyUp={(e) => {this.handleKeyPress(e, 'phone')}}/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4d2fz0wk/

Comment: `e.keyCode` is deprecated (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) use `e.key` instead (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

Comment: @evolutionxbox for example, when press enter key, instead of return 13, return Enter (as string), I need to get 13

Comment: Use e.key instead of e.keyCode.

Comment: `charCode` is not `keyCode`. `charCode` is not only deprecated, but non-standard (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode). Use `key` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the key from `keyCode` of the event:

```
let KeyCode = e.keyCode;
```

Comment: Please make the suggestion to use `key` instead?

Comment: `e.keyCode` return right, when I press enter it return 13, but when I use `e.key` it return `Enter` instead of 13. Thanks @Arman

Comment: @evolutionxbox `key` will return the character of the pressed key, but @tour want the code of the key.

Comment: @ArmanTaherian I understand, but that functionality is likely to be removed in future browsers. It should not be used.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I know, but he said he don't want to use the others event listeners, if not he should use keyboard event-listeners, but anyway `key` is not the answer, because it's hard to get the keyCode from the keyChar.

Comment: I don’t get why the OP _needs_ the codes. Also, `key` can be accessed on all key events, up, down and press.

Comment: @evolutionxbox one of the reason could be Unicode char or other language keyboard. For instance, `keyCode` of *'a'* in an English keyboard is 65, but *'a'* key in Persian is *'ش'*, but the keyCode is 65, exactly like *'a'*. So you can support multilingual key binding.

Comment: Yeah I can see that being helpful if you want to use the same code, but the OP is asking for `Enter` which should be the same in _all_ languages.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [event.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key):

```
handleKeyPress = (e, type) => {
    let key = e.key;
    console.log(key)
    console.log(type)
  }
```